# How to use Graphics@Rotate@Show@Graphics without "Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

Tags: graphics

If I have the following graphic:

```
Rotate[Show[{
   Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
   Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
   Graphics@Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False]}], Pi/3]
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I only want to rotate the content of the graphics, not the frame.

Normally you would use `Graphics` after rotate, however this doesn't work:

```
Graphics@Rotate[Show[{
  Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
  Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
  Graphics@Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False]}], Pi/3]
(* Error: Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive. *)
```

Comment: OT: Does anyone else also think that the design of `Rotate` and associates is somewhat unfortunate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is, that `Plot` already creates a `Graphics` object, which cannot be set inside another `Graphics`. Why don't you extract the contents of your plotted `Graphics`?

```
Graphics@Rotate[{Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
   First@Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False]}, Pi/3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `MapAt` to apply rotations (or other transformations) on parts at position `{1}` of a graphics object.

```
g = Show[{Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}],   Graphics@Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}],
Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False]}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g, MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/3] &, g, {1}]}]
```

[image]

```
 g2 = Graphics[{Line[{{0, -1/2}, {0, 1}}], {Thick, Blue, 
 Line[{{0, -1/2}, {1, 1}}]}, {Opacity[.5, Red], 
 Disk[{-1/4, 2/3}, {1/2, 1/4}, {-Pi/3, Pi}]}, 
 Plot[x Sin[6 x + 4], {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02], Orange}][[1]]},
 ImageSize -> 300];
 Row[{g2, MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/3] &, g2, {1}]}]
```

[image]

**Applying `Rotate` to individual parts:**

```
 Grid[Partition[Column[{Row[{"Rotate  ", #}],
  MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/3] &, g2, {1, #}]}, Center] & /@
  {All, 1, 2, 3, 4, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {3}],
 Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {25, 20}, Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]

**Other transformations:**

```
 g2B = MapAt[ GeometricTransformation[#, 
  ReflectionTransform[{Cos[Pi/3], Sin[Pi/3]}]] &, g2, {1, 4}];
 Row[{g2, g2B, Show[g2, g2B]}]
```

[image]

```
 g2C = MapAt[ GeometricTransformation[#, 
 ShearingTransform[Pi/4, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]] &, g2, {1, 4}];
 Row[{g2, g2C, Show[g2, g2C]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to wrap each `Line` into a `Graphics` statement. Same holds for `Line` which can take more than two points as argument.

To rotate the lines you have to transform the coordinates, not the final output box. Here I use the general command `GeometricTransform`:

```
Graphics@GeometricTransformation[
  Line[{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}}], RotationTransform[Pi/3]]
```

[image]

Comment: However I actually have other functions in show than `Line`, for example `Plot` and Circle, so I can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the desired result without `GeometricTransformation` by putting the `Rotate` *inside* the `Graphics` but *before* `Line`:

```
Graphics@Rotate[Line[{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}}], Pi/3]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using other Graphics types than `Line`, so this won't work.

Comment: Then please edit your post with an example that does not work like this. I'm pretty sure we can find a very similar solution to that. `;)`

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Presentations Application (I'm the author) is, I believe, much more convenient and intuitive for doing this kind of thing. Curves and primitives such as Line are all treated on the same level. No need to repeatedly jump between graphics levels. The transform operations have also been repackaged as postfix operators. You can rotate all the primitives as a group inside of the Draw2D wrapper (similar to Show). Everything is rotated inside of the frame. So this operation looks like the following:

```
<< Presentations`

Draw2D[
 {{Draw[x^2, {x, -1, 1}],
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}],
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]} // RotateOp[\[Pi]/3]},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> 250
 ]
```

[image]

With rotation you may want to specify the center of rotation as a second argument in the RotateOp statement.