# Problem using Rotation in Show

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, graphics

I would like to have an animation of rotating box and displayed it with other elements (not rotated) using Show. The first step to do that is to have all the elements working properly. So I did the following:

1. Created a box:

   ```
   myBox = Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}];
   ```

   and make a Graphics3D out of it:

   ```
   Graphics3D[myBox]
   ```
2. Rotated it:

   ```
   Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox], Pi/2, {0, 0}]
   ```
3. Used Show:

   ```
   Show[Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox], Pi/2, {0, 0}]]
   ```

And the strange things started to happen.

I've got "Show::gtype: Rotate is not a type of graphics.". So I googled and found the following: [link1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18608/how-to-use-graphicsrotateshowgraphics-without-graphics-is-not-a-graphics-pri), [link2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/issue-in-displaying-a-rotated-polarplot-with-show), [link3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57803/how-to-combine-one-or-more-rotated-graphics-objects)

I tried most of the suggestions from those threads and the only one that helped was halirutan's from the first one:

```
    Show[Graphics@First@Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox], Pi/2, {0, 0}]]
```

There was no error, but also no rotation, so the problem was still not solved.

Then I tried:

```
    First@Show[Graphics@Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox], Pi/2, {0, 0}]]
```

The image was rotated, but it wasn't Graphics, so I couldn't use Show on it.

I suppose that answer is somewhere in the threads I quoted, but either I missed it or I can't use it.

Comment: For 3D you need a 3D vector inside `Rotate`, e.g., `Show[Graphics3D[Rotate[myBox, Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}]]]`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by applying `Show`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myBox = Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}];
Show@MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}] &, Graphics3D[myBox], {1}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Table[Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 30],
    Green, Cylinder[{{30, 30, 30}, {40, 50, 40}}, 30]}],
    MapAt[Rotate[#, k, v, {0, 0, 0}] &, Graphics3D[myBox], {1}],
    Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}],
   {k, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/12}] // ListAnimate,
 {{v, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is that you are not interested in doing a rotation of the 3D object inside the 3D scene, but instead want to do a 2D rotation of the displayed `Graphics3D`, as if the latter were just another 2D `Graphics` element.Then you want to combine the result with additional 2D `Graphics` using `Show`.

For this task, the right tool is simply to use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html). Here is an example:

```
Show[
 Graphics[
  Inset[
   Rotate[
    Graphics3D[myBox, ImageSize -> 300], Pi/4, {0, 0}] ]
  ],
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image: block rotated]

Here I used the same commands as in the question, except to change the rotation angle to something more obviously "rotated". Then I specified `ImageSize` options for both the `Graphics3D` and the final `Show`. This, together with the options for `Inset` and the choice of `PlotRange` in `Graphics`, can be used to place the rotated object arbitrarily. Here I didn't include that because there were no other objects to be displayed. But the `Show` framework is all you needed, and from there everything works as it always does in `Show`.

In principle, you can also do away with `Rotate` completely and use the options of `Inset` directly to rotate the content in 2D.

Comment: Looks better if you add the option `Boxed -> False` option to `Graphics3D`. You know that, but I think it's worth pointing out to our readers with little *Mathematica* experience.

Comment: I probably still don't understand something. If I want to show it with second box it doesn't work:  


`myBox2 = Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}];`

`Show[Graphics[Inset[Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox1], Pi/4, {0, 0}]]], myBox2]`

Comment: Sorry for the second comment, some PC problems. It should have been:

`Show[Graphics[Inset[Rotate[Graphics3D[myBox1], Pi/4, {0, 0}]]], Graphics3D[myBox2]]`

@m_goldberg answer helps, but I would like to know why there is an error if I use Show.

Comment: You can't combine 2D and 3D graphics within a single `Show`. It's either one or the other, so you have to apply the conversion to 2D to both objects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
myBox = Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}];

Show@MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}] &, Graphics3D[myBox], {1}]
```

is a good method.

I have an another way to solve this problem.

```
myBox = Graphics3D[Cuboid[{-40, 40, 0}, {40, 60, 10}]];

Graphics3D[Rotate[myBox[[1]], Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]]
```

Compare with the above method, it is simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Keep in mind that `myBox[[1]]` leave all options `myBox` could've had while `MapAt` preserves them

Comment: Yeah, it is mainly used for Show[ the rotation of the graphics ]. Except for rotation, if you want to do something else. It is not necessarily the best.