# Fix " not a Graphics primitive or directive" error in Dynamic Locator Pane

Tags: graphics, locator

I am aware this might seem like a duplicate, however, I have viewed these posts ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191736/graphics-is-not-a-graphics-primitive-or-directive) & [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18608/how-to-use-graphicsrotateshowgraphics-without-graphics-is-not-a-graphics-pri?rq=1)) and have been unable to solve this.

```
   DynamicModule[{pt = {.5, .5}, ll = {}, 
  base = {White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (AppendTo[ll, #]; pt = Last@ll) &], 
  Dynamic[Show@
    Graphics[{base, 
      With[{newpts = Partition[ll, 2, 1]}, 
       Table[{i, Line[newpts[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[newpts], 1}]]}]
   ]]]
```

[image]

Would someone be able to help me to solve this error? Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things in your code were unnecessary (e.g. the `Show` before `Graphics`) and others were confusing and the cause of your trouble. Note that [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) will take a list of points and construct a polygonal line from it automatically; you do not need to produce each segment in a separate `Line` statement, so the `Partition` and `Table` bits can be avoided.

This works with no errors:

```
DynamicModule[
 {pt = {.5, .5}, ll = {}, base = {White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]}},
 LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pt, (AppendTo[ll, #]; pt = Last@ll) &],
   Dynamic@Graphics[{base, Line@Partition[ll, 2, 1]}]
 ]
]
```